How to sum indexed and matched array values
I have a tough problem (for me).  I am trying to get a sum of values from a pivot table, based on a multidimensional array indexed and matched values.
My pivot table looks like this:



Unit Num.
Count Sum




802000
15


502000
12


803038
6


804056
17



and so on.
My index table looks like this:



A
B
C
D
E
F




201
202
203
101
102
103


801000
802000
803000
501000
502000
503000


801002
802002
803002
501002
502002
503002


801003
802003
803003
501003
502003
503003


801004
802004
803004
501004
502004
503004



and so on.
I have a cell for index selection at cell W4 which is a simple drop down box selector for index numbers 201, 202, 203, 101, 102, 103, etc.
In other cells, I do a vlookup of the pivot table based on the unit number of the indexed column to display the count sum information:
=VLOOKUP(INDEX($Z$1:$AZ$61,2,MATCH(W3,Z1:AZ1,0)),'Asset Pivot'!C:D,2,FALSE)
so if I have selected index number 202, it is looking at the unit number for row 2 under the 202 column, in this case 802000. Then it grabs the data from the pivot table for unit 802000 and displays the value 15.
This all works great. The problem is, I also have a selection of "ALL" for the index selection. I cannot get this to work. The desire is to display the sum of all data for the given row. Basically, I want the cell to display the sum of units in row 2, for all the index numbers. So, 201 row 2 unit number sum plus 202 row 2 unit number sum plus 203 row 2 unit number plus.... etc.
I'd like to try and do this with a formula somehow and not delve into VBA code, though I wouldn't be opposed to that either.
I hope this isn't too confusing and that somebody would be willing to help me figure this out. Thank you all.
I was able to get a sum of each row with the following formula:
=VLOOKUP(INDEX($Z$1:$AZ$61,ROW(),MATCH(101,$Z$1:$AZ$1,0)),'Asset Pivot'!C:D,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(INDEX($Z$1:$AZ$61,ROW(),MATCH(102,$Z$1:$AZ$1,0)),'Asset Pivot'!C:D,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(INDEX($Z$1:$AZ$61,ROW(),MATCH(103,$Z$1:$AZ$1,0)),'Asset Pivot'!C:D,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(INDEX($Z$1:$AZ$61,ROW(),MATCH(104,$Z$1:$AZ$1,0)),'Asset Pivot'!C:D,2,FALSE)

But that only gave me a sum in a completely new column next to the index table. I can't figure out how to get those values into the desired cells while maintaining the current functionality.

Just figured it out. Was over thinking it.

I was overthinking it. Easiest way to do what I wanted was to use an IF statement to select to display by the ALL column or the Indexed lookup based on whether ALL or something else was selected.
=IF(W3="ALL",AZ5,VLOOKUP(INDEX($Z$1:$AZ$61,5,MATCH(W3,Z1:AZ1,0)),'Asset Pivot'!C:D,2,FALSE))

